# React-native-webview is not loading all the assets from the html file

Tags: react-native, webview

while trying to load a html file in a webview in react native using the react-native-webview component . the component loads the file but not all its assets  , in the other hand if i load the same file using the deprecated Webview component from react-native(the deprecated one it would work )

Comment: You need to add more detailed informations. Maybe describe which assets are not loaded, maybe send a link to the Page you've tried to load in your webview. And also please describe, what you've tried so far to debug this.  (Did you had a look at `logcat` [if it's on android] to catch some error-messages?

Answer (score 0):

setting the allowFileAccessFromFileURLs prop to true will solve this problem .